# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities Exception - When comparing two DateTime values in LINQ where condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm getting 
    **The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. 
    Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are 
    supported.** Exception

when trying to compare two Datetime values in a LINQ where condition.

I have used DbFunctions.TruncateTime as well, but still Im getting the same exception.

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;    
documents.Where(d => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.ExpirationDate.Date) < DbFunctions.TruncateTime(now));
```

Comment: How about `TruncateTime(d.ExpirationDate)` ?  Calling the .Date property should be  redundant and it matchs your error message.

Comment: Also, `var now = System.DateTime.Now.Date;` is at least an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue was with .Date portion. So instead of using

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;    
documents.Where(d => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.ExpirationDate.Date) < DbFunctions.TruncateTime(now));
```

I'm using

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;    
documents.Where(d => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.ExpirationDate) < DbFunctions.TruncateTime(now));
```

Furthermore, following also works without any issues.

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;    
documents.Where(d => d.ExpirationDate < now)
```

Credit should go to this resource - [The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities Exception - Entity Framework](https://cmatskas.com/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-exception-solution-ef/)

Answer (score 1):

How about ?

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;    
documents.Where(d => d.ExpirationDate < now)
```

or

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;    
documents.Where(d => d.ExpirationDate.Date < now.Date)
```

Comment: No, I have tried both of above. Actually LINQ to Entities cannot translate most .NET Date methods into SQL since there is no equivalent SQL. So have to use DbFunctions.TruncateTime or EntityFunctions.TruncateTime [deprecated].

Comment: Actually 1st option works. Problem was with .Date part of it. Just removed and it worked like a charm. thanks